# is it possible to redirect to another page with id from the previous page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

[image]

So as you can see on a page I have Shop name and it's adress. Moreover I have an edit function on views.py:

```
def update_shop(request, id):
    context = {}

# * fetch the object related to passed id
    obj_shop = get_object_or_404(VideoLibrary, id=id)


# * pass the object as instance in form
    form_shop = VideoLibraryForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj_shop)


# * save the data from the form and
# * redirect to detail_view

    if form_shop.is_valid():
        form_shop.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')

    context['form_shop'] = form_shop

    return render(request, 'update/update_shop.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
...
path('list_view/', views.list_view, name='list_view'),
path('shop/<id>/update', views.update_shop, name='update_shop'),
```

The image is on a different page ('lilst_view') and the issue is - I need to place a button on this page and redirect to the update page in order to edit certain shop names for example. To do this as I suppose I need to get somehow the id of the object. Does anybody know how to do it?

list_view.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      {% for data in library_dataset %} Shop name:
      <br />
      <br />
      {{ data.shop_name }} <br />
      {{ data.adress }} <br />

      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

views.py (def list_view):

```
def list_view(request):

    context = {}

    context['library_dataset'] = VideoLibrary.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'app/list_view.html', context)
```

Comment: share the list_view code

Comment: You need to update list_view.html page with id of library_dataset and then there will href which will direct you to the shop page where you can edit shop data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#list_view.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      {% for data in library_dataset %} 
      Shop name:
      <br />
      <br />
      {{ data.shop_name }} <br />
      {{ data.adress }} <br />
      <td><a href="{% url 'update_shop' data.id  %}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Shop Details</button>
    </a>
</td>

      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have already written all your code correct you just need to update list_view.html page

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can do it in **Django** by simply useing [**redirect()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) method with parameters, for example

```
return redirect('some-view-name', parameter_name='par_value')
```

and in **a** tag put `<a href={% url 'view_name' desired_id %}`

Comment: where should i put this code?

Comment: sorry for not explaining the code well.  after updating the item in the shop you should redirect the customer to the view, so you should put the redirect() in the end of updating function